change Windows partition from RO to RW at login
I'm have installed Devuan Daedalus in my friend's computer. It is a HP laptop with AMD RYZEN 3 and Radeon Graphics.
It has Windows 11 also installed. Windows partition has been shut down fully (not hibernated, not Quick ShutDown either).
To access the Windows partition inside Linux, I did the following:

created a directory Windows in the home directory

issued a mount command from the terminal    : sudo mount /dev/nvmen1p3 /home/user/Windows

added the following line in /etc/fstab (the fstab file was edited using gnome-disk-utility Mount Options):


/dev/nvmen1p3 /home/user/Windows ntfs-3g nls-utf8,umask=0222,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,auto,owner,users,exec,x-gvfs-show 0 0

After Step #2, the Windows partition is mounted with Read-Write permissions.
But after restarting the system, the Windows partition is mounted with Read-Only permissions.
How can I get the Windows partition mounted with Read-Write permissions after restarting the system? I believe that the fstab parameters allow Read-Write. But don't know what's happening

You have specified umask=0222 in the mount configuration. This shows all files as read-only.
I suggest you remove it
